# Синтез речи на Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, text-to-speech

Как можно сделать синтез речи(То-есть пишешь текст, а программа этот текст говорит) на node js. Я нашел один модуль `say`, но при работе данной программы

```
const say = require('say')
say.speak('Hello!')
say.stop()
```

Появлялась ошибка:

```
internal/process.js:167
  throw new TypeError('invalid pid');
  ^

TypeError: invalid pid
at process.kill (internal/process.js:167:13)
at SayPlatformLinux.runStopCommand (/root/node_modules/say/platform/linux.js:41:13)
at SayPlatformLinux.stop (/root/node_modules/say/platform/base.js:139:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/NodeJs/speech.js:7:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
```

P.S Операционная система linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внимательнее читайте ридми. Вам нужно установить дополнительные пакеты:

```
sudo apt install festival festvox-kallpc16k
```